# Is there any documentation on how Jenkins' Pipeline suite of plugins is (internally) structured?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

While trying to find where the `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowDefinition` class is defined, I grepped through the main Jenkins repository and several of the `workflow-*` plugins' repositories until I finally found it in `workflow-api-plugin`.

There must be a better way to do this. Is the structure of the Pipeline plugin suite -- i.e. what functionality goes in which plugin -- documented anywhere?

(Just to be clear, the question is not "*how do I write a Jenkins pipeline?*", but "*can I avoid searching through >10 plugins in the Pipeline plugin suite?*")

Answer (score 1):

Select your job, choose "Pipeline syntax" on the left, then choose the plugin you want, configure it, and click "Generate Pipeline Script".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I want to look up a plugin and its arguments I use the offical [Pipeline Steps Reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/) documentation where the functionality is listed . I think every plugin can be found here.

The plugins are also listed on the [Plugins Index](https://plugins.jenkins.io/) where you can usually find a lot of information as well.

If you are looking for basic pipeline syntax the official [Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) documentation is probably the best you can find.

Jenkins is very well documentated so I can highly suggest to use the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you, the first link is quite useful. I'm afraid I wasn't clear enough, so I've updated the question to clarify it.